# dependabot only updates lock file

Tags: github, package.json, package-lock.json, greenkeeper, dependabot

We've recently switched from `greenkeeper` to `dependabot` for our dependencies checks and we noticed that `dependabot` is opening PRs changing only `package-lock.json` leaving `package.json` as it was.

On the other hand, `greenkeeper`, was committing changes to both files.

What is going on? Is it normal or we missed something in the settings?

Comment: hey @Johnny, did you manage to find an adequate solution to this?

Comment: @flaky yes. There's a configuration setting in the dependabot configuration file which forces all updates to be written to package.json also. You should have a look thorough GitHub's dependabot documentation. I might write an answer about it to better explain what to do.

Comment: I'd love a nice explanation :) 
The dependabot docs are hit and miss sometimes :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a very late reply. We had this working in production for a long time now, but I see there's still interest prompting me that maybe people need some help. So, here it is:

When using GitHub dependabot (**not** `dependabot-preview`, although the conf file might be the same, actually):

- create a [`dependabot.yml`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates#about-the-dependabotyml-file) file in your repo's `.github` directory.
- specify a [versioning-strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates#versioning-strategy) of `increase`.

It will look something like this (e.g. `npm`):

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    # Always increase the version requirement
    # to match the new version.
    versioning-strategy: increase
```

That's it. Now, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are both written to with a version increase.

---

Here's the expanded logic behind it.  `package.json` specifies "permanent dependency constraints" on the apps and libraries, while `package-lock.json` tracks a particular set of exact versions that meet all those constraints, to avoid unnecessary variation.  A frequently used constraint type in `package.json` might be a "caret range" and look like this: `^1.2.3`.  The caret character is what is making it a range, rather than an exact version specification.  Apart from allowing exact versions "1.2.3", it also allows "1.2.9" or "1.4.1", but not "2.0.6"; dependabot can often meet all the caret (and other) ranges in your `package.json`, while doing the necessary upgrades, without having to change any of these rather liberal constraints.  Now, the default `versioning-strategy` for packages that are considered libraries rather than apps would be `widen`, i.e., to widen the range as necessary.

Continuing the previous example, if dependabot wants to upgrade a library specified through a caret range as `^1.2.3` (or not constrained at all) from "1.2.3" to "1.4.1", dependabot can leave `package.json` alone, because "1.4.1" is already allowed by `^1.2.3`.  However, if it is necessary to make a major upgrade to "2.0.6", then the caret range has to be made wider.  It would probably end up replaced by something like `>=1.2.3 <=2.0.6` in `package.json`.  If your `package.json` is very thin (few constraints, liberal constraints), dependabot, when using the default versioning strategy, rarely has to update `package.json` at all.

But if you change your npm versioning strategy to `increase`, dependabot will tend to narrow down your caret ranges by increasing their minimums.
Instead of `^1.2.3` which stands for `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0-0`, you could get `^1.4.1` which stands for `>=1.4.1 <2.0.0-0` in your `package.json`.

Apart from the `widen` (which really stands for "widen if necessary"), and `increase` (which kind of stands for "always narrow down so as to exclude older versions than our immediate goal"), there's also a value of `increase-if-necessary` which allows increasing, but only if it is necessary to meet the upgrade goals.  If your `package.json` is very thin (few constraints, liberal constraints), you might not see much difference between `widen` and `increase-if-necessary` because dependabot will generally not judge it necessary to interfere with your required ranges.

The lesson for some of us is that we should read up on the `package.json` syntax possibilities to understand how liberal or specific our existing dependency requirements are, and only then we want to judge dependabot's strategy to their updates, and possibly switch to a different strategy.

Comment: Can you edit this answer to more clearly say why setting "versioning-strategy" causes the package.json file to update? What about this does that? The documentation from dependabot is not clear.

Comment: @AndyRay - here you go.

Answer (score -2):

The goal of the file package-lock.json is to keep track of the **exact version of every package** that is installed so that a product is 100% reproducible in the same way even if packages are updated by their maintainers.
[reference link is here](https://flaviocopes.com/package-lock-json/#:%7E:text=system%20for%20years.-,The%20package%2Dlock.,when%20you%20run%20npm%20update%20.)

So package.json and package-lock.json have different purposes.

There is no error on dependabot trying to push just a modified package-lock.json.

Comment: he didn't ask about an explanation of the difference between `.lock`  and manifest file...

Comment: This helps me understand a bit better about dependabot's upgrade approach. It would be nicer if there's also a suggestion for package.json, since just upgrading package-lock might break the app.

Answer (score -3):

Something similar happened to me, it can be for two things:

1. In the dependendabot configurations you only have to accept updates for package-lock.json
2. (This was the one that worked for me) in the package.json in the key `Name` you may have written with incorrect symbols in my case I had `web-app` the symbol `-` caused me not to update it and now I have it as `webapp`.

Comment: Let me understand, probably 99% of the packages on npm have a '-' sign in their name. If that's the problem, this is a big bug in dependabot (probably already found).

Comment: It's not that, I'm talking about the name of the project in the package.json for example: 
` {
"name": "ProjectN", => This is what I'm talking about.
"version": "1.0.0", 
"description": "Web App", 
"main": "index.js"
}
`
This would be the wrong way
`"name" : "Project-N" `